# Role based authorizations to actions in Java/Struts

Tags: java, struts2, authorization, struts, roles

I have an application based on Java/Struts/Hibernate. It has 2 types of users. Admin and Normal user. I created separate Struts pages for both roles and actions.

But when I type admin action in the URL after logged as Normal user, the admin pages are accessible to the normal user. How can I fix this?

i have entered action class of admin and user are in separate in xml pages and are included in the `struts.xml` page. if you're using the application everything works fine.but consider an action in struts-admin, e.g.: `adminHome`, it will be `localhost:8080/app/adminHome`. if a normal user logged in, the URL will be `localhost:8080/app/normalHome`. But if the normal user types changes `normalHome` to `adminHome`, he can access Admin pages.

**UPDATE:**

As I said earlier, I have admin and user actions in different packages in `struts.xml`. Can I get its package name in Java? Then I compare with `user_role` and direct to admin `/normal` pages..

Comment: post your code first.

Comment: show us some code and what all ides / ways you have in mind.

Comment: edited post. actually i need some authorization methods to perform in my application.

Comment: Which Struts version? Show your code and configuration.

Comment: I already have interceptors in my application. How can I customize it to select admin/user based on the action class?

Answer (score 1):

See this code

In login action class write after user has entered correct details then

```
session.setAttribute("user_id","userid");//store user id in session scope
session.setAttribute("user_designation","userdesignation");//store designation in session scope
```

later return role (user designation) either `admin` or `user` in login action class.

```
return "userdesignation";//admin or user
```

in struts.xml write forwards conf to login action like

```
<action input="/index.jsp" name="Login_Check" path="/login" scope="request" type="com.mycompany.Login_Action" validate="true">
<forward name="admin" path="adminhome.jsp"/>//if action returns `admin`
<forward name="user" path="userhome.jsp""/>//if action returns `user`
</action>
```

In respective JSPs check designation like

```
if (session.getAttribute("user_designation").equals("admin"))//for admin JSPs (ex: adminhome.jsp)
{
     ..............//JSP content
}
else
response.sendRedirect("some page");

if (session.getAttribute("userd_esignation").equals("user"))//for user JSPs(ex: userhome.jsp)
{
     ..............//JSP content
}
else
response.sendRedirect("some page");
```

If `true` then only display respective JSP. Otherwise Plz! redirect him/her to login or index and display a message.

Comment: Thanks.
But all the links in admin are accessable to user. So do I have to add this 'if' statement in every jsp pages of admin?

Comment: add if con to every JSP.

Comment: @Donyboy, Add if condition to every JSP page. First 'if' cond to every admin JSP and second 'if' cond to every user JSP. Make sure that the user designation must be stored in session.

Comment: i am not sure about applying it in all the pages. is there any other ways? 
can we do it from the struts? 

i have all the admin actions in one package and user actions in another package in struts.xml.

Comment: No. We need to check role in each Page. Otherwise how it's possible to redirecting a user to particular pages.

Comment: @Donyboy, it will not be practical to change 4k+ JSPs. So use struts2 role based interceptors.

Comment: could you give me some examples for role based interceptors?

Comment: Do you think this is a good solution for huge applications using struts2 ?

Comment: @JABBARITaoufik, Its not recommended. Look my above comments

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`roles`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/roles-interceptor.html) interceptor to suit your needs.

> This interceptor ensures that the action will only be executed if the user has the correct role.

It has two parameters:

- `allowedRoles` - a comma-separated list of roles to allow
- `disallowedRoles` - a comma-separated list of roles to disallow

that you can configure in the action config. For example

```xml
<!-- only allows the admin roles -->
<action name="adminAction" class="com.examples.AdminAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="roles">
      <param name="allowedRoles">admin</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result>good_result.ftl</result>
</action>

<!-- only allows the member roles -->
<action name="memberAction" class="com.examples.MemberAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="roles">
      <param name="allowedRoles">member</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result>good_result.ftl</result>
</action>
```

This way you can use a roles interceptor to restrict access to the actions.

Comment: Don't post a code in comments. If you have a different question then post it in a separate thread.

Comment: Sorry for posting code.
How do i specify admin or member role in struts?  i only have entries in db to specify roles or in session.

Comment: If you have another question, you can ask it in the other page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580862/role-based-authorization-using-struts2-interceptors